# Error on Injecting dependencies into your ZF2 controllers

Tags: zend-framework2, servicemanager

Hi I am having errors trying to inject dependencies on my controllers.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for User\Controller\LoginController::__construct(), called in /var/www/html/engsvc_dev/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170 and defined in /var/www/html/engsvc_dev/module/User/src/User/Controller/LoginController.php on line 23

Module.php

```
    public function getControllerConfig(){
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Login' => function ($sm) {
                $locator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                $controller = new LoginController($locator->get("Config"));
                return $controller;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Controller

```
class LoginController extends AbstractActionController{

protected $globalConfig;

protected $UserModuleSetup;

public function __construct($config){

}
```

module.config.php

```
    "invokables" => array(
    "User" => "User\Controller\LoginController",
    "Login" => "User\Controller\LoginController"
),
```

Comment: I guess that your `Login` definition in `module.config.php` is overriding the definition in `Module.php`. Try to remove the `Login` line in `module.config.php`

Comment: I've already tried that earlier. that resulted to this error Fatal error: Class 'User\LoginController' not found in /var/www/html/engsvc_dev/module/User/Module.php on line 39

Comment: Maybe because you call "User" without config passed to constructor

Comment: that fix it. Thanks!

Comment: please set this topic as closed or delete it, or auto answer it.

Comment: please do as @Unex suggested in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Module.php

```
    public function getControllerConfig(){
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Login' => function ($sm) {
                $locator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                $controller = new User\Controller\LoginController($locator->get("Config"));
                return $controller;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Controller

```
class LoginController extends AbstractActionController{

protected $globalConfig;

protected $UserModuleSetup;

public function __construct($config){

}
```

module.config.php

```
    "invokables" => array(
    "User" => "User\Controller\LoginController",
),
```